# Dash apps with basic_scaling/manual_scaling on Google App Engine

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine, plotly-dash

I had my Dash app working perfectly fine with GAE on automatic scaling types. My app.yaml was simply:

```
runtime: python38
instance_class: F4_1G
entrypoint: gunicorn --timeout 2400 -b :$PORT application:application
```

But it turns out some calculations run over the 10 minute limit that is set for automatic scaling types.

So I have read that the solution is either to speed up my code (I don't think it's way inefficient), or to switch to manual/basic scaling, which don't have the 10 minute timeout.

I have tried changing the app.yaml to:

```
runtime: python38
instance_class: B4_1G
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
  idle_timeout: 25m

entrypoint: gunicorn --timeout 2400 -b :$PORT application:application
```

But with this all I get is this when visiting the site:

> Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not
> complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.

And the Google Logs Viewer shows this:

```
E 2020-10-14T10:48:20.982385Z GET 403 135 B 23.2 s Unknown /_ah/start
A 2020-10-14T10:48:23.327231Z [2020-10-14 10:48:23 +0000] [10] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4 
A 2020-10-14T10:48:23.329063Z [2020-10-14 10:48:23 +0000] [10] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (10) 
A 2020-10-14T10:48:23.329085Z [2020-10-14 10:48:23 +0000] [10] [INFO] Using worker: sync 
A 2020-10-14T10:48:23.602018Z [2020-10-14 10:48:23 +0000] [17] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 17 
A 2020-10-14T10:48:34.192067Z OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k 
A 2020-10-14T10:48:44.211122Z [2020-10-14 10:48:44 +0000] [10] [INFO] Handling signal: term 
A 2020-10-14T10:48:44.218051Z [2020-10-14 10:48:44 +0000] [17] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 17) 
E 2020-10-14T10:48:44.241493Z GET 403 135 B 27.7 s Unknown /_ah/start
A 2020-10-14T10:48:44.617622Z [2020-10-14 10:48:44 +0000] [10] [INFO] Shutting down: Master 
A 2020-10-14T10:48:47.486868Z [2020-10-14 10:48:47 +0000] [10] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4 
A 2020-10-14T10:48:47.487984Z [2020-10-14 10:48:47 +0000] [10] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (10) 
A 2020-10-14T10:48:47.488006Z [2020-10-14 10:48:47 +0000] [10] [INFO] Using worker: sync 
A 2020-10-14T10:48:47.781489Z [2020-10-14 10:48:47 +0000] [17] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 17 
A 2020-10-14T10:49:03.100870Z OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k 
A 2020-10-14T10:49:11.991812Z [2020-10-14 10:49:11 +0000] [10] [INFO] Handling signal: term 
A 2020-10-14T10:49:11.996679Z [2020-10-14 10:49:11 +0000] [17] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 17) 
E 2020-10-14T10:49:12.105306Z GET 403 135 B 10 s Unknown /_ah/start
A 2020-10-14T10:49:12.398334Z [2020-10-14 10:49:12 +0000] [10] [INFO] Shutting down: Master 
A 2020-10-14T10:49:14.560845Z [2020-10-14 10:49:14 +0000] [10] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4 
A 2020-10-14T10:49:14.562372Z [2020-10-14 10:49:14 +0000] [10] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (10) 
A 2020-10-14T10:49:14.562602Z [2020-10-14 10:49:14 +0000] [10] [INFO] Using worker: sync 
A 2020-10-14T10:49:14.732882Z [2020-10-14 10:49:14 +0000] [17] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 17 
A 2020-10-14T10:49:18.757532Z OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k 
A 2020-10-14T10:49:22.157248Z [2020-10-14 10:49:22 +0000] [10] [INFO] Handling signal: term 
A 2020-10-14T10:49:22.164939Z [2020-10-14 10:49:22 +0000] [17] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 17) 
A 2020-10-14T10:49:22.666466Z [2020-10-14 10:49:22 +0000] [10] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The warning ‘OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k’ usually appears when there is not enough memory. What is the memory usage when you encounter the error? Is it hitting the limit for the instance class ‘B4_1G’?

Comment: F4_1G (where it works fine) and B4_1G both have 2gb so I didn't think it could be the memory. At this point of the memory usage is very low, it's just to show a front page menu.

Comment: The logs show the error is generated when booting the worker. Could you check the memory consumption at the time of starting the worker? Please review your application code and dependencies. It would also be worth trying to use App Engine Flexible environment and set up the resource setting with more memory, or create a VM instance on Google Compute Engine to deploy your app, to see if they help resolve the issue.